# error de sintaxis en python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

¿Por qué al ejecutar este bloque me aparece error de sintaxis? No logro encontrar el porqué:

```
 for Empleados in cursor:
     emplead = '\t'+ str(Empleados[0]) + '\t'+ str(Empleados[1]) + '\t' + 
     str(Empleados[2]+ \
     '\t' + str(Empleados[3] +'\t' + str(Empleados[4] + '\t' + str(Empleados[5] 
     + '\t' + str(Empleados[6])
     print (str(emplead))
```

Este es el error que me muestra:

```
print (str(emplead))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

La cadena es de 2 líneas, agradezco orientación.

Comment: Hola, tal vez sea porque te falta cerrar con paréntesis algunas de las llamadas a `str()`

Comment: cesar, gracias hombre, asi es, que falta de descuido, novatada. te agradezco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error era porque te faltó cerrar algunas de las llamadas a la función `str()` y eso suele pasar cuando concatenas de esa manera. Una forma más sencilla de hacerlo es formateando la cadena de texto:

```
for Empleados in cursor:
     emplead = '\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s' % (
         Empleados[0],
         Empleados[1],
         Empleados[2],
         Empleados[3],
         Empleados[4],
         Empleados[5],     
         Empleados[6]    
     ) 
     print(emplead)
```

Ahora se ve más ordenado que antes y es más facil de leer también.

Comment: o tambien puedes usar la funcion `format` que ya viene en python3.4 para el tratamiento con strings

Comment: @ReinierHernándezÁvila así es. Mi respuesta se basa en las costumbres de Python 2 y algunas costumbres son difíciles de evitar.

Comment: En python 3.6 se puede hacer aún más conciso: `emplead = "".join(f"\t{e}" for e in Empleados)`

Comment: entonces aplicando la funcion format tambien me imprime estilo columna los datos:

Answer (score 5):

El error se debe a tener paréntesis sin cerrar como comenta César. Estos errores son más fáciles de cometer en líneas tan largas como esa, además de hacer el código poco legible. Puedes usar el método [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) y simplificas mucho el código:

```
for Empleados in cursor:
    emplead = '\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}\t{}'.format(*Empleados)
    print(emplead)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(N):
    i = 0
    while (2 ** i < N):
        i = i + 1
    return i


print(func(64))
```

hola ya esta bueno si pero tengo otro problema por que  meda resultado de 7 y necesito es 6 como lo hago.